# React Native EXPO (+EAS) - iOS WidgetKit

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, expo, eas

I would like to ask if there is a way to use Expo Managed Workflow with EAS CLI with WidgetKit of iOS without ejecting from Expo.
Thanks :)

I searched online but couldn't find anything

Answer (score 1):

Yes this seems to be possible now. I haven't had the time to try it out myself but this repo provides an example to build and iOS and Android Widget in Expo Managed workflow:

https://github.com/gaishimo/eas-widget-example

Comment: Can this widget also be added to the lock screen?

Comment: The widget in the repo seems to be a 'normal' widget designed for the home screen. But since the code is native, is should also be possible for the lock screen with some modifications.

Comment: There isn't any documentation on it online